# connection pooling for wcf httpbinding

Tags: wcf, http

For http based wcf service, is there any connection pooling that happens internally? Will the connection be opened and closed for every http request? Through some search, I found something called `keep-alive` setting but didn't really understand how it works in wcf scenario. Is it possible to implement connection pooling at all for `httpbinding` service. Below is the use case we have.

The end client system is informatica which consumes wcf service developed by us. Our wcf service in turn calls another external web service (I am not sure if it is a wcf implemented service or on another different platform, not sure if there is a way to dynamically detect this other than asking the vendor).

We would be making thousands of calls to the external service within a span of time and want to optimize it. Send lot of data within a single call is not an option provided by the vendor service yet.

I think opening/closing connection creates lot of overhead. Is there a way to pool the connections for re-using it for http based service?

Thanks,
Shyam